# HighCharts - Set default Axis options for my extension

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Im trying to create a vertical solid gauge chart with highcharts. It should be really simple, just like a solid gauge but as a vertical bar.

For doing so, I am creating a new series type and extending it from the column chart.

If I set all the options for columns, e.g. hiding the Y Axis labels, hiding the X axis labels, etc. it works more or less like I want to. But, as I am wrapping this into a plugin, I don't think it make sense that the user who defines a chart as a `lineargauge` should have to worry about setting this informations right. **Thus, I need a way to set some default properties to my custom series and I cant find the way to do it.**

I have tried wrapping the `render` and `drawGraph` function. I have tried setting it on the overriden draw functions of my chart. None of these worked.

You can check my progress on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w8ou4byv/1/

What I want, for instance, is that the user of my plugin should not have to set:

```
//...
yAxis: {
    labels: { enabled: false },
}
```

It should be the default value (although it is not the default for the column chart that I am inheriting from).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You use `Highcharts.extendClass` for creating a new series type. Highcharts provides a dedicated function for this called `seriesType`: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#seriesType

`seriesType` accepts default options of a new series as an argument - that's the solution for your problem.

Comment: Hi Kamil, thanks for the answer.
I couldnt get it to work. The options parameters doesnt seem to have the effect I would expect. It doesnt modify the chart at all. Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1dmo6tew/ . Can you provide a fiddle with some default options being set?

Comment: `title` is a property of chart object. The third argument of `seriesType` functions should be **series** options. Example for color property: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x71jr3y0/  You should put the code responsible for changing the default chart options in function of the object passed as the 4th argument, e.g. in `Series.render()`:http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pxfmtndo/ Analyzing of core code will help you to understand how to perform similar operations.

Comment: Thanks Kumil, this seems to be just what I want! I also asked this question on Highcharts forum and another Highchart developer made some considerations performance-wise about this approach: https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/set-default-axis-options-for-my-extension-t40250/
Do you also have any considerations about it? Thanks

Comment: Right, the solution that involves wrapping `Chart.prototype.init` function is much more elegant and faster. I recommend to use it.